# Access OpenVPN Client From IP eth0

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn

Hi i just followed many thread in here but i cannot done it yet. I just wanna to access my client openVPN that has ip 10.8.0.2 via my public IP 34.101.xx.xxx

My server has Ubuntu Server that installed OpenVPN. If i connect OpenVPN, it can ping between two client. just like this
`Client 1 (10.8.0.2)  ==>  Client 2 (10.8.0.3)`

But if i disconnect Client 1, Client 2 cannot ping Client 1 even use my public IP (34.101.xx.xxx)

I browsing over internet and has diagram like this

```
______________________         _______________
|   UBUNTU SERVER    |         |  Client 1    |
|   (34.101.xx.xxxx) |         | 10.8.0.2     |
|____________________|  <===>  ________________
|  | OPENVPN   |     |             
|  | (10.8.0.0 |     | 
______________________
```

Can my phone without client OpenVPN reach Client 1 with just using IP of Ubuntu Server?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do exactly; why are you surprised that if you disconnect Client 1 from the VPN that you can no longer see it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to do exactly; why are you surprised that if you disconnect Client 1 from the VPN that you can no longer see it?

VPN is not (in my experience, anyway) used to allow other private clients to be accessible from the public Internet. A VPN is by definition *private*. A VPN server allows known VPN clients to access that private network like a router, but that network is not designed to be available to the rest of the Internet. Your phone would also need VPN client software and connect to the VPN server to be able to see that network.

Comment: I just wanna access my device such as camera, because my isp doesn't give a public ip.